# Creating new column from columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 pandas dataframes *df1* and *df2*

df1

| id | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe | 16 |
| 2 | Jane | 17 |

df2

| id | score |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 16 |
| 2 | 8 |

then I am merging both dataframes:

```
mergedf = df1.merge(df2, on='id', how='left')
```

and after all I will create a new dataframe, that should have columns id and name from *df1*, and column score from *df2* and adittionally a new column (diff) that will be the difference between score and age and another column called status that will be the result of the following `if 'age' == 'score' then 'OK' else 'false'`

This is the code of the new dataframe

```
newDF = mergedf[['id','name','score','diff', 'status']]
```

But it is still not clear for me how should I nest this code

```
if 'age' == 'score' then 'OK' else 'false'
```

to generate the the new columns diff and status.

Comment: please don't paste images of code or data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `diff` to calculate the difference across the columns and then use `numpy.where` for your condition

```
mergedf = df1.merge(df2, on='id', how='left')
mergedf['diff'] = mergedf[['age', 'score']].diff(axis=1)['score']
mergedf['status'] = np.where(mergedf['diff'] == 0, 'OK', False)
print(mergedf)

   id  name  age  score  diff status
0   1   Joe   16     16     0     OK
1   2  Jane   17      8    -9  False
```